# Ruby regex - stop when found first of two chars

Tags: ruby, regex, puppet

Lets say that i have the following array with 4 elements:

```
myArray = [
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-icu/2.4.2",
    "lukas-vlcek/bigdesk/2.5.0",
    "royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ",
    "polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor"
]
```

When iterating, I want to assign a substring to a variable, resulting in:

```
0) analysis-icu
1) bigdesk
2) HQ
3) inquisitor
```

I have tried the regex `(.*\/(?:elasticsearch-)?(.*)(?:\/.*|\z))` but it doesnt stop at the `/`

How can i make it match until the end of each element string OR at the second `/`, if there is one?

Online tester here: http://rubular.com/r/t8ws1BbOU6

---

If you're into [puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/), full code below:

```
elasticsearch::plugin {[
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-icu/2.4.2",
    "lukas-vlcek/bigdesk/2.5.0",
    "royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ",
    "polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor"
]}
```

And:

```
$es_plugin_dir = regsubst($name, '(.*\/(?:elasticsearch-)?(.*)(?:\/.*|\z))', '\2')
```

Comment: Does this work alright: `^[^\/]*?\/(?:[^\/-]*?\-)?([^\/]*?)(?=\/[^\/]*?$|$)` ? See http://rubular.com/r/jD86CW3vTt.

Comment: Why `analysis-icu`rather than `elasticsearch-analysis-icu` or `icu`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland because thats the name of the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me [this regex](http://rubular.com/r/a0attcRsx1) should work for you:

```
(^[^\/]*?\/(?:[^\/-]*?\-)?([^\/]*?)(?=\/[^\/]*?$|$).*)
```

And here is your updated code:

```
$es_plugin_dir = regsubst($name, '(^[^\/]*?\/(?:[^\/-]*?\-)?([^\/]*?)(?=\/[^\/]*?$|$).*)', '\2')
```

Comment: Perfect. Just a slight modification: `(^[^\/]*?\/(?:[^\/-]*?\-)?([^\/]*?)(?=\/[^\/]*?$|$).*)` replaced by `\2`